Unity + C# bouncing animation
I'm currently working on a slot game in unity and what I'm trying to achieve is that once the reels stop spinning, the symbols bounce a little bit up and down before they come to a full stop.
In my code, this method currently handles the stopping of the reels:
private void Update(){
if(stopInitiated) {
           speed= 0;
}
}

This currently just sets the speed of the reels to 0 directly. If the value for  float speed is negative, the reels move up and if the value is positive the reels move down. Is there a way to manipulate the value for speed such that a nice little bounce effect is created ?
I tried using this example script for EasingFunction but I don't exactly understand how the methods work.
I tried:
private void Update(){
if(stopInitiated) {
           speed =  EasingFunction.EaseOutBounce(-0.10f, 0.00f, 0.50f);
}
}

However, the only thing that happens is that as soon as the stop is initiated, the reel just start spinning upwards forever. I think the Update() method calls float EasingOutBounce everytime it is being executed, so this might be what's resetting the speed value. Can you give me a hint on how to properly implement such an easing function ?
Otherwise, I would also be happy to accept an alternative solution like lerp, as long as it leads to a bounce effect.
Appreciate your help !

well once it stops, its not to be initiated again, reset it?

There is a different if-statement that handles the situation when speed is equal to 0. However, that is never happening.

I believe the best way to do this would be to simply change the variable back to false so Update() does not called the code in the if statement repeatedly:
private void Update(){
    if(stopInitiated) {
        speed =  EasingFunction.EaseOutBounce(-0.10f, 0.00f, 0.50f);
        stopInitiated = false;
    }
}

This way, it is only called once, creating the bounce effect.
